# Субъективное сравнение скорости работы Python3 и Golang в задаче записи чисел в 2 файла

Tags: python, golang

Написал идентичный код на обоих языках :

```
import os

file1 = open("z1.txt", "w")
file2 = open("z2.txt", "w")

for x in range(-1000, 1000):
    for y in range(-1000, 1000):
        z1 = (x + y) * (x + y)
        z2 = x * y

        args = str(x) + "\t" + str(y) + "\t"
        toFile1 = args + str(z1) + "\n"
        toFile2 = args + str(z2) + "\n"
        file1.write(toFile1)
        file2.write(toFile2)

file1.close()
file2.close()
```

```
package main

import (
  "os"
  "strconv"
)

func main() {
  file1, _ := os.Create("z1.txt")
  file2, _ := os.Create("z2.txt")
  for x := -1000; x < 1000; x++ {
    for y := -1000; y < 1000; y++ {
      z1 := (x + y) * (x + y)
      z2 := x * y

      args := strconv.Itoa(x) + "\t" + strconv.Itoa(y) + "\t"
      toFile1 := []byte(args + strconv.Itoa(z1) + "\n")
      toFile2 := []byte(args + strconv.Itoa(z2) + "\n")
      file1.Write(toFile1)
      file2.Write(toFile2)
    }
  }
  file1.Close()
  file2.Close()
}
```

Неожиданный сюрприз - на golang работает 12 секунд в худшем случае,а на python за 7. В среднем случае гоу тоже сильно отстаёт, было проведено коло 30 запусков. Более того, golang сам по себе работает в 2 потока с этой программой, что казалось бы должно ускорить запись в оба файла.

У меня было подозрение, что я в гоу использовал слишком низкоуровневые функции как-то неверно и решил реализвать тот же код на си:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(){
    FILE* f1 = fopen("z1.txt","w");
    FILE* f2 = fopen("z2.txt","w");


    for (int x =-1000; x <1000;++x ){
        for(int y =-1000; y <1000;++y ){
            int z1 = (x+y)*(x+y);
            int z2 = x*y;

            fprintf(f1,"%d\t%d\t%d\n",x,y,z1);
            fprintf(f2,"%d\t%d\t%d\n",x,y,z2);
        }
    }
    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);

    return 0;
}
```

Тут ничего удивительного - си выполняет всё мигом.
Ладно, попробовал в гоу сишную реализацию, стало ещё хуже - 22секунды в среднем.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    file1, _ := os.Create("z1.txt")
    file2, _ := os.Create("z2.txt")

    for x := -1000; x < 1000; x++ {
        for y := -1000; y < 1000; y++ {
            z1 := (x + y) * (x + y)
            z2 := x * y

            fmt.Fprintf(file1, "%d\t%d\t%d\n", x, y, z1)
            fmt.Fprintf(file2, "%d\t%d\t%d\n", x, y, z2)
        }
    }
    file1.Close()
    file2.Close()
}
```

Далее Я попробовал оптимизировать код на го и сделал запись в файл 1 раз, вместо записи в цикле, и хранил буфер в одной строке, аналогично сделал на питоне и ничего не изменилось, я не могу понять в чём дело, почему golang в этой задаче отстаёт.

Версия с рукописным буфером го:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    file1, _ := os.Create("z1.txt")
    file2, _ := os.Create("z2.txt")
    var toFile1 string
    var toFile2 string
    for x := -1000; x < 1000; x++ {
        for y := -1000; y < 1000; y++ {
            z1 := (x + y) * (x + y)
            z2 := x * y

            args := strconv.Itoa(x) + "\t" + strconv.Itoa(y) + "\t"
            toFile1 += (args + strconv.Itoa(z1) + "\n")
            toFile2 += (args + strconv.Itoa(z2) + "\n")

        }
    }

    file1.Write([]byte(toFile1))
    file2.Write([]byte(toFile2))

    file1.Close()
    file2.Close()
}
```

По возможносте дайте пожалуйста подробный ответ, а не "в гоу там доп действие - конвертация в байты". Заранее спасибо)

> python3
> Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> go version go1.21.6 linux/amd64

Comment: Протестировал у себя, очень странно, получил похожие результаты. Питон в этой задаче действительно отработал быстрее.

Comment: В питоне файл открывается в режиме только запись. В го на запись и чтение. Попробуйте добавить флаг O_WRONLY. Не знаю влияет ли, просто заметил разницу)

Comment: @Alpensin 1:49 XD

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `bufio` в `Go`.

Comment: Файловые буфера, файловые буфера...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Файлы в Го лишены буферов. Каждая операция записи в файл приводит к записи на диск. Программа получает управление после того как от операционной системы получена гарантия что данные записаны на диск. Тест:

> ```
> $ time go run temp.go 
>
> real  0m12.011s
> user  0m4.660s
> sys   0m7.384s
> ```

Огромное время в строке `sys` - время ожидания записи данных на диск.

Добавим буфера:

```
package main

import (
  "bufio"
  "os"
  "strconv"
)

func main() {
  file1, _ := os.Create("z1.txt")
  file2, _ := os.Create("z2.txt")
  buf1 := bufio.NewWriter(file1)
  buf2 := bufio.NewWriter(file2)
  for x := -1000; x < 1000; x++ {
    for y := -1000; y < 1000; y++ {
      z1 := (x + y) * (x + y)
      z2 := x * y

      args := strconv.Itoa(x) + "\t" + strconv.Itoa(y) + "\t"
      toFile1 := []byte(args + strconv.Itoa(z1) + "\n")
      toFile2 := []byte(args + strconv.Itoa(z2) + "\n")
      buf1.Write(toFile1)
      buf2.Write(toFile2)
    }
  }
  buf1.Flush()
  buf2.Flush()
  file1.Close()
  file2.Close()
}
```

Стало гораздо лучше:

> ```
> $ time go run temp.go 
>
> real  0m1.554s
> user  0m1.428s
> sys   0m0.112s
> ```

В Питоне и в Си буфер встроен прямо в объект-файл, вы сразу получаете хорошую производительность, но нет гарантий записи данных прямо в момент записи. Гарантия появляется только после сброса буфера.

Для ориентировки ваш код на Си у меня отрабатывает почти наравне с буферированным Го:

> ```
> $ time ./a.out 
>
> real  0m1.336s
> user  0m1.168s
> sys   0m0.080s
> ```

А вот что будет если в Си добавить сброс буферов в цикл (`fflush(f1); fflush(f2);`). Снова семь секунд ожидания записи:

> ```
> $ time ./a.out 
>
> real  0m11.220s
> user  0m4.220s
> sys   0m6.912s
> ```

Comment: Действительно так, СПАСИБО! Однако, подскажите пожалуйста, почему мой рукописный буфер в строке работал ещё дольше?

Comment: Покажите ваш рукописный буфер. Если его написать неаккуратно, можно всё испортить.

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: `+=` на строках копирует всю строку целиком. С ростом длины строки операция `+=` замедляется. Это приводит к квадратичной сложности. На коротких файлах вы будете выигрывать, на длинных проигрывать. Не надо так делать кеши. Почитайте https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760757/how-to-efficiently-concatenate-strings-in-go

Comment: А аналога `StringBuilder`/`StringBuffer` в `Go` нет случайно? )  P.S. А, по ссылке всё есть...